# Probability of questions being on an exam

Tags: probability

My girlfriend has an exam in her international development class tomorrow.  She's been given $60$ terms to study (each takes a long time to learn thoroughly).  Of those $60$ terms, $10$ will be on the exam, and she must discuss $3$ of them.  Now, she's been spending a lot of time trying to figure out the probability of knowing $x$ of the $3$ questions, time that could be spent studying.

Funnily enough, I actually have a probability and statistics for computer science final coming up next week and I have no idea how to figure out this probability. Given that she studied $n$ of $60$ terms, what is the probability that she will know (a) $0$, (b) $1$, (c) $2$, (d) $3$ of the $10$ terms that appear on the exam?

Comment: I don't see why this has been voted down.  It does present a useful probabilistic question and has background for why he asked it.  I am voting it up.  My only comment is that $x \in \[0,3\]$ is not the correct notation but rather $x \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, assuming that is what you are asking.  I am voting up.

Comment: Interesting applied problem! For solving the problem, it is natural to assume that all $\binom{60}{10}$ choices by the examiners are *equally likely*. This is *unlikely*, since probably there will be an attempt to space the terms more or less evenly across the curriculum. It is a hard problem to decide by how much this might affect our conclusions.

Comment: Doesn't this fit better on Cross Validated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The chance that she will know none of them is the chance that none of the $10$ on the test matches one she studied.  The test makers have to pick $10$ times without hitting.  So it is $\dfrac {(60-n)(59-n)\ldots(51-n)}{60\cdot 59 \ldots 51}=\dfrac {(60-n)!50!}{60!(50-n)!}$

The chance she will know all three is picking $3$ of the $n$ she studied and $7$ of the others, so $\dfrac {{n \choose 3}{60-n \choose 7}}{{60 \choose 10}}$  You can probably see how to do $1$ and $2$.

Comment: I think something might be wrong.  When I compute $\dfrac{\binom{60}{3}\binom{60-60}{7}}{\binom{60}{10}}$ I get 0.. Also, subbing in $n=30$ is giving me ~10%.

Comment: Is it perhaps 1 minus that answer? (as $n$ decreases, the probability decreases.. Shouldn't it be the opposite?)

Comment: @somekindarukus:  for the first, you have the top values in the numerator wrong.  For the third-the probability of knowing $0$ should decrease as $n$ increases, and it does, as there are more terms to multiply.  It is also $\dfrac {{60-n \choose 10}}{{60 \choose 10}}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Perhaps it should be noted that the probability $\dfrac{\binom{n}{3}\binom{60-n}{7}}{\binom{60}{10}}$ that you gave is the probability that she will know **exactly** three terms; thus it makes sense that for large values of $n$, that probability decreases, because she will likely know more than three terms if she has studied a large number of the terms.

Comment: The probability that she will know **at least** three terms is $\dfrac{\binom{n}{3}\binom{60 - n}{7}+\binom{n}{4}\binom{60 - n}{6}+\binom{n}{5}\binom{60 - n}{5}+\binom{n}{6}\binom{60 - n}{4}+\binom{n}{7}\binom{60 - n}{3}+\binom{n}{8}\binom{60 - n}{2}+\binom{n}{9}\binom{60 - n}{1}+\binom{n}{10}}{\binom{60}{10}}$

Answer (score 9):

This is no more than a generalization of Ross Millikan's answer. What you/she needs in called hypergeometric probability. There are $n$ total unique items (questions in your case), of then $m<n$ are sampled without replacement (i.e. they are not returned to the set). There are $x<m<n$ special items in this sample (in your case $0 \leq x \leq 3$. We use some special mesh size $r$ to select $r$ items out of $m$. We want to know the probability to have $x$ special items in this mesh.

Clearly there are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways to select $m$ items out of $n$. Since we want $x$ special items in the mesh (And the rest does not matter), there are $\binom{r}{x} \binom{n-r}{m-x}$ ways of doing so. Hence, the probability to catch $x$ special items is 
$$
P(X=x)=\frac{\binom{r}{x} \binom{n-r}{m-x}}{\binom{n}{m}}
$$