# Hypergeometric Distribution Problem With Rocks!

Tags: probability, statistics

The question I am working on is:

> A geologist has collected 10 specimens of basaltic rock and 10 specimens of granite. The geologist instructs a laboratory assistant to randomly select 15 of the specimens for
>   analysis.
>
> a.What is the pmf of the number of granite specimens
>   selected for analysis?
>
> b.What is the probability that all specimens of one of the
>   two types of rock are selected for analysis?
>
> c. What is the probability that the number of granite specimens selected for analysis is within 1 standard deviation of its mean value?

For part b), I calculated the probability as $2 \cdot h(10; 15, 10, 20) + 2 \cdot h(5;15,10,20)$

I multiplied 2 by each hypergeometric distribution, because there are 2 ways to pick all of the rocks of the same type, and 2 ways of picking 5 rocks of the same type. However, this isn't the correct answer. What is wrong with my reasoning?

For part c), I calculated the average value to be 7.5, which is correct; my variance would then be $V(X) = \frac{10}{19} \cdot 7.5 \cdot (1-\frac{10}{20})$. In the answer key, though, they have $\frac{5}{19}$ for their first term. Why is that?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252901/probability-of-questions-being-on-an-exam/252956#252956

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are $n_b$ basaltic rocks, and $n_g$ granite rocks, and we sample $n_b + n_g > m > \max(n_b, n_g)$ rocks at random among $n_b+n_g$ equiprobably. There is the total of $N_T =\binom{n_b+n_g}{m}$ orderless configurations.

The number of configurations where $k$ granite rocks are selected is $ \binom{n_g}{k} \binom{n_b}{m-k}$, making the probability
$$
      \mathbb{P}\left(k \text{ out of } m \text{ rocks are granite} \right) = \frac{\binom{n_g}{k} \binom{n_b}{m-k}}{\binom{n_b+n_g}{m}} \tag{1}
$$
The event that all granite rocks are sampled, corresponds to event $\{n_g \text{ out of } m \text{ rocks are granite}\}$, while the event that all basalt rocks are sampled corresponds to the event $\{m-n_b \text{ out of } m \text{ rocks are granite}\}$. These events are disjoint, therefore
$$
  \mathbb{P}\left(\text{All specimens of one of the two types of rock are selected }\right) = \frac{\binom{n_b}{m-n_g}}{\binom{n_b+n_g}{m}} + \frac{\binom{n_g}{m-n_b} }{\binom{n_b+n_g}{m}}
$$

To answer the last question use expression $(1)$ for pmf to compute the mean, and the standard deviation, find $k$ that satisfy the requirement and add pmfs at those values.

Comment: For part c), why do you suggest I use expression $(1)$? Why can't I just use the Variance formula for a Hypergeometric distribution: $V(X) = \frac{N-M}{N-1} \cdot E(X) \cdot (1-\frac{M}{N})$?

Comment: Because the problem asks you to compute $\mathbb{P}\left( (X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2 < \mathbb{Var}(X) \right)$ which is to say to sum $ \sum_{k=m-n_b}^{n_g} \mathbb{P}\left(X=k\right) \left[ (k-\mathbb{E}(X))^2 < \mathbb{Var}(X) \right]$, where $\left[ \ldots \right]$ denotes the indicator function, also known as [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: This is how they calculate $V(X)$ in the answer key to my textbook: $V(X)= \frac{5}{19} \cdot 7.5 \cdot (1- \frac{10}{20})$. I just want to know why 5/19 is in the calculation, shouldn't it be 10/19?